# Yii2 GridView comparing Column content data to other controller rendered param

Tags: gridview, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-model

I've created a Yii2 Gridview widget and i'd like to display "V" mark only on row equals another renderred variable i pass from controller:

```
        <?=
             GridView::widget([
                               'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                               'filterModel' => $searchModel,
                                'columns' => [
                                        [
                                            'header' => 'Default',
                                            'content' => function ($model) {
                                              if ($model->id == $selected) {
                                                return Html::tag('i','',['class' => 'fa fa-check']);
                                              }
                                              return '';
                                            }
                                        ],
```

passing from controller:

```
    return $this->render('index', [
        'selected' => $selected,
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
```

But i receive an error:

> Undefined variable: selected

What did i miss?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable `$selected` does not exist within the scope of the anonymous function. From the [php.net page for anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php):

> Closures may also inherit variables from the parent scope. Any such variables must be passed to the `use` language construct.

i.e:

```
'content' => function ($model) use ($selected) { ...
```

Comment: Worked! Thank you so much!